# Wrapping directive of ng-repeat not finding child elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want my wrapping directive to get elements within and bind events to them.
My markup is like this:

```
<div wrapping-directive>
   <div ng-repeat='item in items'></div>
</div>
```

What i want is to get all the items created by the ng-repeat within the wrapping directive, like this:

```
app.directive('wrappingDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var items = element.find('div'); // this returns an empty array
        // if i write $(element).find('div'); it returns an empty array as well
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe lay the directive directly on the items and give them the events.

```
<div>
   <div ng-repeat='item in items' event-directive></div>
</div>

app.directive('eventDirective', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          $(element).click( //
      }        
    }
});
```

Or inject the list with the directive itself.

```
<div wrapping-directive>

</div>

app.directive('wrappingDirective', function() {
    return {
       scope: {
         "items": "="
       },
       template:"<div ng-repeat='item in items' ng-click='doSomething(item)'></div>",
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $scope.doSomething = function(item){
            //
           }
       }
    }
});
```